# Open redirect Fortify issue

Tags: c#

Recently I started working on some of security issues logged by fortify tool.
I was working on **Open Redirect** issues where i found that we need encode our Querystring parameter values so i tried the same approch in my sample application but when i observered, the input data was not getting encoded.

I tried something like below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1 = TextBox1.Text;
        string s11 = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s1);
        Server.UrlEncode(s1);
        Server.HtmlEncode(s1);
        Response.Redirect(Server.UrlPathEncode("WebForm2.aspx?&Name=" + s11));
   }
```

When I saw the value during debug time it is not encoded , please help me what am missing here. Is there any other way i can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is you are looking for

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string s1 = TextBox1.Text;
     string s11 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s1);
     Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?&Name=" + s11));
 }
```

Comment: This dint work I changed it to HttpUtility.UrlEncode still the value is not gettting encoded.